# Base de Datos SQL integer primary key autoincrement

Tags: sql

El problema es que tengo una base de datos

```
Android
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table articulos(codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, producto TEXT)");
    }
```

el problema es que porque me empieza a registrar el autoincremento desde 1 para arriba y yo necesito que empieze desde el 0 para arriba
es que con la posicion del puntero yo compruebo si es igual ala columna codigo si el primer registro 0 pero como primer registro es 1 no funciona lo que quiero,
además sumarle +1 al puntero para que me valide si 1 == 1 se crashea la aplicación por lo que la única opción es que se registren desde 0 en la columna codigo que se autoincrementa y es la llave primaria.

Comment: Hola amigo que base de datos tienes?

Comment: Es con SQLiteOpenHelper base de datos interno en el sistema android